# Baking AO has weird results

Tags: texture-baking, baking, ambient-occlusion

This is the first time I've ever dealt with baking textures so bear with me.
I want to bake some ambient occlusion into a low poly mesh I have here, but the results are really jarring. I followed this short tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChxGAcKO92Y

Here are some minor artifacts I get here:[image]

But worse is this pitch black segment here, it makes no logical sense as there's nothing here that would cause the lighting to be occluded.

[image]

I don't have any loose geometry, everything is created as it should, albeit in quads and lowpoly, but I don't believe that should be causing giant black stripes to be created. Am I baking AO the wrong way, or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Some object might be hidden, but still affects in baking

Comment: The overshadowing on the edges is likely due to overlapping or very closely situated vertices. Can you upload a screenshot of the wireframe? And, as Crantisz mentions, are any objects in our scene hidden? Can you maybe show what's in your Outliner?

Comment: Woops, yes it was due to a hidden object. But I still have those slight artifacts around the edges, in the first screenshot. This is my entire scene. https://imgur.com/a/2mzHMWk

Are there any other options to baking AO, I'd like to increase the strength of it.